# jQuery AJAX load Question

Tags: javascript, jquery

For reasons unknown, this code snipnet isn't working:

```
$("#lbxArea").live ('change', function () {
    $("#lbxStation").load ('../data/stations',
                           { areaID: $("#lbxArea").val () });
});
```

I can see on Firebug that the request goes out and the data comes back and looks good. `lbxStation` is a `<select>` element and the returned data is HTML of `<option>` elements. When this runs, the select element doesn't change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me:
http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/aabeb.php

```
<form>
  <select id="lbxArea">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select>
</form>
<div id="lbxStation"></div>
<script>
$("#lbxArea").live ('change', function () {
    $("#lbxStation").load ('ajax.php?html=test',
                           { areaID: $("#lbxArea").val () });
});
</script>
```

Comment: The problem is I know it should work for me. What browser were you using, just out of curiosity?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (But I didn't test out)

```
$("#lbxArea").live ('change', function () {
    $.get('../data/stations',{ areaID: $("#lbxArea").val () }, function(data){
       $("#lbxStation").html(data);
    });
});
```

EDIT: Check now....

Comment: That's not what I want. The point is that the return data goes into the next select box, not the one that triggered the event.